# restResponse sslStream is disposed upon response before fully reading the stream C#

Tags: c#, rest, http, stream

I'm using restSharp.dll objects (`RestClient`, `RestRequest` & `RestResponse`) to read massive amounts of data from a server.

As i know the full response will take time, i would like to process the data received immediately without waiting for the full response. Hence the usage of the `ResponseWriter` property:

```
RestClient restClient = new RestClient("base URI here");
RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("relative URI here", RestSharp.Method.GET);
restRequest.ResponseWriter = new Action<Stream>(ReadStream);

IRestResponse restResponse = restClient.Execute(this.restRequest);


                    if (restResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    {
                       // More code
                    }
```

ReadStream being:

```
     public async void ReadStream(Stream ms)
        {
            bufferSize = 1024             
            do
            {

                byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                bytesRead =await ms.ReadAsync(tempBuffer, 0, bufferSize); 

                //Data handling

            } while (bytesRead > 0 && ms.CanRead());
        }
```

The thing is that the remote server processes my query much faster than i will be reading the stream with the `ReadAsync` method,
and it seems that when the server returns a response, the `SslStream` is disposed leaving me with data i have yet to read. The erreor i get is:

> bytesRead =await ms.ReadAsync(tempBuffer, 0, bufferSize); >> Cannot
>   access a disposed object. Object name: 'SslStream'

Am i utilizing the `ResponseWriter` incorrectly? Is there a way to keep reading the stream after receiving the response form the server?

Thanks,

Comment: "Am i utilizing the streamWriter incorrectly?" -- I don't see any StreamWriter in your code?

Comment: The response string is http and you really can't parse http until you get the entire response.  Most parsers require the closing tag of an element otherwise you will get an exception.

Comment: @canton7 My bad, i meant the ResponseWriter, a RestRequest method